# Formula to Count the Number of Unique Vertices in a Grid?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, geometry

I'm trying to find a mathematical formula that will return the number of vertices for an $m x n$ grid of elements. The tricky part is that any grid element is allowed to span multiple rows or columns.

Let's define the bottom left corner of a grid element as it's position and say that the origin [x=0,y=0] of any grid is the bottom left corner, where +x is to the right and +y is up.

Here are some examples to help one visualize the problem: [Click Here to See Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxvTg.png). The description grids 1, 2, and 3 are:

1. 2x2 Grid - comprised of (2) 1x1 elements at positions [0,0] and [0,1] (1) 2x1 element at position [1,0]
2. 2x3 Grid - comprised of (4) 1x1 elements at positions [0,1] [1,1] [2,1] [0,2] and (1) 1x2 element at position [0,0]
3. 2x4 Grid - comprised of (3) 1x1 elements at positions [0,0] [2,1] [3,1], (1) 1x2 element at position [0,1], and (1) 1x3 element at position [1,0]

**If for an $mxn$ grid we know the total number of grid elements ($cnt$) and for each grid element we know it's position ($[x , y]$) and size ($l$ x $w]$), is there a formula that we may derive to calculate the number of *unique* vertices in said grid?**

*** Note that *unique* vertices are shown as blue dots in the aforementioned  [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxvTg.png)

Thank you

Comment: What does "span multiple grid elements" mean? In the image, it seems you may be referring to the lines (drawn as double lines in image) which connect the grid elements. The term "collage" is also not defined in the question, and isn't a familiar one, at least to me. You refer to size of elements, maybe it means lengths of the lines joining grid elements... I think in sum this question needs more explanation as to what data you start with, from which the count of the blue dots is looked for.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Let me ask the question with three better images:

Comment: You need not only more images, but you need to address the concerns in my comment as to definitions, data given, etc.

Comment: I just edited the original question, hope this helps coffee

Comment: In the third case (actually a 2x4 base) if the lower row has its square and long rectangle switched, the count goes from 12 blue dots (as in your diagram) to only 11 blue dots. (This is then an example of what David K said in his answer, showing count cannot be obtained from just the shapes of component rectangles and how many of each.)

Comment: hi, i edited the original question even further, I hope that this makes things easier to understand - I defined the origin, size of a grid element to be l x w and position of an element to be [x,y] and updated the example image. please let me know if this is easier to understand now. Thanks!

Comment: With knowing the positions and dimensions, assuming these are (length, width) with lengths going horizontally, the total number of "unique" vertices (your blue dots) can indeed be found without constructing the filled-in grid. But the counting method involves looking at adjacent rows and checking for equal partial sums, and is a bit involved to explain. Interested? If so maybe you could come up with some examples to try it on.

Comment: To moderators-- IMO the latest edits of the question make it clear what is asked, so maybe take it off "hold"?

Comment: I am interested in the equal partial sums method, if it's complicated to explain can you refer me to a paper or textbook? I also don't know how to remove this post from on-hold.

Comment: Since the question is now "on hold" no more answers can be posted for it. That makes it hard to explain the method here in a comment for lack of space, I haven't seen any method for this count in a paper or text, or anywhere else for that matter. But for each pair of adjacent rows you put the rectangle lengths in order to compare the partial sums, since each equal partial sum indicated an internal vertex of degree four, the others all of degree three.

Comment: Brio50 It seems although I voted to reopen it needs 2 more votes from other users for it to be reopened. I don't know if you would be allowed to be one of those two votes, however.

Comment: Shall I just post in a new thread, also any recommendations on the category this question belongs in? Thanks for your time coffee!

Comment: I should say that my "counting equal partial sums: idea only works provided all rows go clear across the board. If a horizontal border starts out from the left but then bumps into a vertical rectangle and pokes into its side rather than flush with top or bottom my count fails (can't even set it up).

Comment: The current version of the problem asks for "a mathematical formula that will return the number of vertices in an $m\times n$ grid", and your linked images help to visualize what is meant by this output.  What remains unclear is the input data upon which said "mathematical formula" is expected to act.

Answer (score 1):

For a larger grid with elements of different sizes, you can often rearrange the position and/or orientation of elements in the grid in order to have more "blue" vertices or fewer "blue" vertices.

So merely knowing the sizes of the elements and how many you have of each is not enough information. You also need to know how each element was placed in the grid.